# Create a new Eclipse Project for Xampp

Tags: eclipse, xampp

You guys would not believe this. On the internet, there is not a single shred of documentation on creating a new NON REMOTE Eclipse project. Its crazy stuff. All I am trying to do is create a local Eclipse project pointing to a local xampp directory. Impossible.

**Question:** How do I create a non remote, local eclipse project pointing to a local xampp directory on windows.

Comment: `All I am trying to do is create a local Eclipse project pointing to a local xampp directory.`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to create a remote eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

just change your workspace(in eclipse File->Switch workspace->Other) to the directory in xampp and create your project.
thats it ;)